# ¿Es posible ejecutar de manera externa la tecla TAB al llegar el input a una longitud?

Tags: javascript, formularios, tab

Os pongo en contexto, tengo varios inputs de tipo number y quiero que al tener por ejemplo el primer input un carácter se pase automáticamente al siguiente (cosa que creo que solo es posible a través de la tecla TAB). Para ello, pensé en intentar ejecutar de manera externa o mejor dicho, desde la web un TAB cuando llegase a la cantidad de caracteres querida, pero no funciona, ¿cómo lo podría hacer? Dejo mi código:

```
    $(document).on('keyup','[id=1]',function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == 1) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
         //esta función lo único que hace es ver si se ha ejecutado el tab en ese input
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yo lo que haría es que cuando cumple el lenght del primer input se le pase al siguiente haciendole un `.focus()` al input siguiente

Answer (score 0):

Si lo puedes hacer de esta manera con javascript en el primer input haces un evento que se lance cada vez que presionen una tecla. Miras que el valor de dicho input sea igual a la longitud que quieres y después le haces un focus al siguiente y así...

```js
function Limite(input){
  if($(input).val().length == 1){
    $('#segundo').focus()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="primero" onkeydown="Limite(this)" />
<input type="number" id="segundo" />
```